# Provide a custom class for a ListView's convertView

Tags: android

My app implements a ListView. Each item in the list displays a photo and some text. Both of these are downloaded from the internet. I would like to provide my own custom class for the convertView specified in the ListAdapter, so that I can update it when an image has downloaded. However, I cant figure out quite how to supply an alternative to View (I created a subclass that extends view, but when I changed the default method signature

```
View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

to

```
View getView(int position, MyViewClass convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

I got a compile error.

How can I supply my own class for convertView?

Answer (score 0):

```
I would like to provide my own custom class for the convertView
```

If you need two or more types of views for your `ListView` adapter, then you need to override in your adapter [`getViewTypeCount()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getViewTypeCount%28%29) and [`getItemViewType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29). First method returns how many types of view you'll have, while the second type returns what type of view you should have for the current item position. Something like:

```
abstract class MyListAdapter implements ListAdapter {

    /**
     * Set this up in your constructor
     * */
    private Context context;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_SUPERMAN = 1;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_BATMAN = 2;
    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(position % 2 == 0) { // your business logic
            return VIEW_TYPE_BATMAN;
        }
        return VIEW_TYPE_SUPERMAN;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
        if(convertView == null) {
            if(viewType == VIEW_TYPE_BATMAN) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(resource_id_for_batman, parent);
            } else {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(resource_id_for_superman, parent);
            }
            // setup a ViewHolder pattern implementation
        } else {
            // get your ViewHolder from convertView
        }
        // update your views from ViewHolder
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

further reading: `so that I can update it when an image has downloaded`. For this reason you don't need to have a separate view and type. You only need to know for each item (based on its position) if: image was not downloaded, image failed to download, download is in progress or image was downloaded. So I would implement the `ViewHolder` pattern by adding this piece of information. So you'll have a single view type and for each case you'll decide what to do (trigger a download, fetch the image from cache/sdcard or show a default image). To think this better, I believe you'll need to have a separate structure in your adapter implementation, but not in `ViewHolder` since the `ViewHolder` object will be tied to recycled views.

The code above (to add an overloaded `View getView(int position, MyViewClass convertView, ViewGroup parent)`), should compile unless you have an `@Override` annotation. Without the annotation you'll have an overloaded method that will not be called.